# Query more than 50000 records in a normal class

Tags: apex, soql, batch, query, querylocator

I need to query more than 50000 records and store it in a List variable. i know there is a governor limit which prevents it. please let me know if this can be accomplished without going for a batch class.

will getQueryLocator work in a normal class... please help.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Why do you need more than 50,000 rows? What are you attempting to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Simmer '18, [The SOQL Count() Function Doesn’t Count (As Much) Toward Limits](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_soql_count_limits.htm) so you can count way more than 50,000 records.

If you are working from a Visaulforce page, setting `readOnly="true"` lifts the limit to 1,000,000 rows (see e.g. [Setting Read-Only Mode for an Entire Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_readonly_context_pagelevel.htm)) but other limits such as the heap size still apply.

But the general solution when wanting to work with large numbers of rows is to move to asynchronous Apex such as batchable where `QueryLocator` can be used.